# Why I can't redirect using `hosts` file in windows?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ip, redirection, hosts-file

I want to go to `www.Google.com` when I enter `1.1.1.1` in my browser. So I think I must change `hosts` file under `windows\system32\drivers\etc` path in Windows to map this IP address to Google homepage.

I changed it as below :

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost


    1.1.1.1     www.google.com
```

But still when I enter `1.1.1.1` in the browser, the browser doesn't redirect and search for the real `1.1.1.1` and I receive **This webpage is not available** error!

**Update:**

Well, based on the comments, I replace the previous line with following lines:

```
178.22.78.1 https://www.google.com
178.22.78.1 www.google.com
```

Now, I expect my browser to open `178.22.78.1` when I enter `www.google.com`. But still I receive **This webpage is not available** error!

Why my redirection doesn't work?

Comment: it works the other way around.  What you've done is when you type www.google.com into the browser it will actually go to IP 1.1.1.1 which presumably has no website.

Comment: @User Question Updated. please take a look

Comment: you want that when people type www.google.com you redirect their request to you hosted site on this IP 178.22.78.1?

Comment: @emirjonb That's an example. Yes, I want it.

Comment: than this depends on you web server that host that site. It should be enabled to handle the url www.google.com.

Comment: @emirjonb When I write `178.22.78.1` itself in the browser, it opens my target destination successfully!

Comment: where is you site hosted, a local server? what server apache, iis?

Comment: @emirjonb What do you mean by "this" site? Do you mean `178.22.78.1`? Nope, it's not a local site. It's a website and I think you can see it. I don't have any idea about the server.

Comment: when you make a http request your browser use that url to make the request to you webserver. The webserver normally has a rule to check if the url is valid and than respond to your browser. if the url is not valid drop the request(potentially this is your case). So first you need this setup on your windows and than need to make changes to the server too

Comment: the server administrator will have set some rules. see here http://serverfault.com/questions/593895/deny-requests-for-other-domains-in-apache-2  ore here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872892/htaccess-deny-requests-from-unauthorized-domains

Answer (score 2):

the file works as an DNS server, it just resolve names CN to IP. If you use IP directly it doesn't do any resolve

Answer (score 1):

Within your hosts file, you enter a name and an IP.  This is so that your computer knows which IP to connect to when you enter a host name/web address - not the other way around.

What you have placed into your hosts file will send you to 1.1.1.1 when you enter www.google.com into a web browser, not www.google.com when you enter 1.1.1.1.

It acts similar to a [forward DNS lookup](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/Forward-DNS-lookup), not a [reverse lookup](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/reverse-DNS) (which converts host name to IP).

Although I have not tried it, it may be worth making an entry for 216.58.208.68 with a hostname of g.g.g.g or simply "g".  This will make getting to google quicker (which I assume is your goal here).  You could also try setting a host name of 1.1.1.1, although I havent tested this and I am not sure how a browser/machine would handle it... it may look it up as a host name or may recognise it as an IP.

Comment: Please check the update section. Based on your answer and other answers I updated the question. It seems that it doesn't work like what you said also.

Comment: NBTSTAT -RR and ipconfig /flushdns then reboot your machine... should have you up and working... hopefully

Comment: I tried, unfortunately didn't helped.

Comment: It seems that is a layer seven problem, http protocol. probably there are some rules on your webserver.